# Exim Systemd Service Times out

Tags: centos, systemd, exim

I have compiled EXIM from source and am trying to get it to run as a service on Centos 7. I created my own `exim.service` file.  The EXIM process starts when I run `systemctl start exim` but systemd believes it times out. It does write the PID file correctly. Everyone has read permissions on the PID file.

Thanks!

Here is the exim.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Exim

[Service]
Type=forking

PIDFile=/apps/exim/spool/exim-daemon.pid

ExecStart=/apps/exim/exim -bd -q15m

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here is the output from `systemctl status exim`:

```
Jan 08 10:54:49 smtp2 systemd[1]: exim.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 08 10:54:49 smtp2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Exim.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help but here is the standard `exim.service` file from CentOS 7 when install Exim from the repositories;

```
[Unit]
Description=Exim Mail Transport Agent
After=network.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service postfix.service

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
Environment=QUEUE=1h
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/exim
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/exim-gen-cert
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/exim -bd -q${QUEUE}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That starts fine for me, as I say just installing from the repository. It already looks pretty much the same as yours but may I suggest copying that and attempting to start exim with that in place to see if that works. If it doesn't then it may be that your installation of exim hasn't worked as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe exim doesn't daemonize? If this is the case, then it needs `Type=simple`. Just check it.

Comment: I believe it does. According the the documentation -bd runs the program as a daemon. [Exim](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x15909.html)